# How can I hide the background of a button using Prism/WPF/MahApps?

Tags: c#, wpf, prism

I'm working through Brian Lagunas' PluralSight tutorial on an introduction of using Prism, as I'm still wanting to grasp the concepts of using MVVM.

I have a button that looks fine, when enabled by the above `CheckBox`:

[image]

However when the `Button` is no longer enabled through Prism's delegate commanding, I'm getting a window around the button.

[image]

How can I remove that box when the `Button` is disabled? I would like to instead change the foreground to make the gear icon a gray color, but will settle on removing that box for now.

Below is the `StackPanel` and the code-behind for what I've tried

XAML code:

```
<StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" Orientation="Vertical">
   <CheckBox Content="CanExecute" IsChecked="{Binding CanExecute}"></CheckBox>
   <Button  Command="{Binding ClickCommand}" Background="#a9afb8" Height="35" Width="35" BorderThickness="0" ToolTip=" Marks the current work order as complete.">
      <Button.Style>
         <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Style.Triggers>
               <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="True">
                  <Setter Property="Background" Value="#a9afb8"></Setter>
               </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
         </Style>
      </Button.Style>
      <iconPacks:Unicons Width="35" Height="35" Kind="Cog" />
   </Button>
   <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}"></TextBlock>
</StackPanel>
```

Code-behind:

```
public class ViewAViewModel : BindableBase
{
   private string _title = "ViewAVM";
   public string Title
   {
      get { return _title; }
      set
      {
         SetProperty(ref _title, value);
      }
   }

   private bool _canExecute = false;
   public bool CanExecute
   {
      get { return _canExecute; }
      set
      {
         SetProperty(ref _canExecute, value);
         ClickCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
      }
   }

   public DelegateCommand ClickCommand { get; private set; }

   public ViewAViewModel()
   {
      ClickCommand = new DelegateCommand(Click, CanClick);
   }

   private bool CanClick()
   {
      return CanExecute;
   }

   private void Click()
   {
      Title = "Clicked";
   }
}
```

Comment: `Background="Transparent"` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is not related to MVVM. Controls in WPF have a visual and logical structure defined in XAML along with states and triggers for those states to change control properties on state changes. This is defined in the control template.

In case of a `Button` there are states like *Pressed*, *MouseOver* or *Disabled* just to name a few. All of these states have a visual representation. For example, in the *Disabled* state, the `Background` will be changed to light grey, and the opacity is reduced. Triggers for that in the control template take precedence over triggers defined in styles, so you need to create a custom control template to change the representation of the *Disabled* state.

As creating custom control template can be complex, you should copy the default control template or style of a control and adapt it. Be aware that the default template may vary depending on the libraries that you use. In case of *MahApps.Metro*, you can find the default button style and template [here](https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/blob/698e4d6fcf81016b05405be13bf66a573057ce4f/src/MahApps.Metro/Styles/Controls.Buttons.xaml#L386).

The part that you are interested in is the trigger for the *Disabled* state.

```
<Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
   <Setter TargetName="DisabledVisualElement" Property="Opacity" Value="0.7" />
   <Setter TargetName="PART_ContentPresenter" Property="Opacity" Value="0.3" />
</Trigger>
```

As you do not want the `Background` to change, but the `Foreground`, replace the `Setter`s like below and adapt the `LightGray` color to the color that you want to have.

```
<Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
   <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="LightGray"/>
</Trigger>
```

If you want to change other states, too, you can it the same way. This is the whole style:

```
<Style x:Key="MyButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ButtonBase}">
   <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource MahApps.Brushes.Gray10}" />
   <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource MahApps.Brushes.Button.Border}" />
   <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
   <Setter Property="Controls:ControlsHelper.ContentCharacterCasing" Value="Upper" />
   <Setter Property="Controls:ControlsHelper.CornerRadius" Value="3" />
   <Setter Property="Controls:ControlsHelper.FocusBorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource MahApps.Brushes.Button.Border.Focus}" />
   <Setter Property="Controls:ControlsHelper.FocusBorderThickness" Value="2" />
   <Setter Property="Controls:ControlsHelper.MouseOverBorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource MahApps.Brushes.Button.Border.MouseOver}" />
   <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{DynamicResource MahApps.Fonts.Family.Button}" />
   <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{DynamicResource MahApps.Font.Size.Button}" />
   <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
   <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource MahApps.Brushes.ThemeForeground}" />
   <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="25" />
   <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5 6" />
   <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />
   <Setter Property="Template">
      <Setter.Value>
         <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ButtonBase}">
            <Grid>
               <Controls:ClipBorder x:Name="Border"
                                             Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                             BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                             BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                             CornerRadius="{TemplateBinding Controls:ControlsHelper.CornerRadius}"
                                             SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
               <Controls:ClipBorder x:Name="DisabledVisualElement"
                                             Background="{DynamicResource MahApps.Brushes.Control.Disabled}"
                                             CornerRadius="{TemplateBinding Controls:ControlsHelper.CornerRadius}"
                                             IsHitTestVisible="False"
                                             Opacity="0"
                                             SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
               <Controls:ContentControlEx x:Name="PART_ContentPresenter"
                                                   Margin="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                                   Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                                   HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                                   VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                                                   Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                                   ContentCharacterCasing="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=(Controls:ControlsHelper.ContentCharacterCasing)}"
                                                   ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding ContentStringFormat}"
                                                   ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                                                   ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplateSelector}"
                                                   RecognizesAccessKey="{TemplateBinding Controls:ControlsHelper.RecognizesAccessKey}"
                                                   SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
            </Grid>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
               <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                  <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource MahApps.Brushes.Gray8}" />
                  <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=(Controls:ControlsHelper.MouseOverBorderBrush), Mode=OneWay}" />
               </Trigger>
               <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                  <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource MahApps.Brushes.Gray7}" />
               </Trigger>
               <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="True">
                  <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=(Controls:ControlsHelper.FocusBorderBrush), Mode=OneWay}" />
                  <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderThickness" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=(Controls:ControlsHelper.FocusBorderThickness), Mode=OneWay}" />
               </Trigger>
               <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                  <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="LightGray"/>
               </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
         </ControlTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
   </Setter>
</Style>
```

You can apply the `Style` and the control template [like below or apply it implicitly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/fundamentals/styles-templates-create-apply-style?view=netdesktop-5.0):

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource MyButtonStyle}" ...>
   <iconPacks:Unicons Width="35" Height="35" Kind="Cog" />
</Button>
```

If you want to know more about the states and structure of a control, you can refer to the documentation on MSDN, for example for `Button` [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/button-styles-and-templates?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8). However, the examples there might be incomplete or a bit dated.

Comment: There's `Background="Transparent"` too

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thanks, that is correct. However, since the original poster is interested in changing the foreground in specific states, I wanted to show a comprehensive answer explaning the what is happening that also applies to default control templates with triggers that might override the `Background` property, where this approach would not apply.

Comment: The title says `hide the background`. Guess it's another case of an XY Problem ... asking about the expected solution, not the actual problem